# Dynamically create AWS S3 buckets in multiple regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-regions

Is there a way to create terraform `aws_s3_bucket` resources dynamically in different regions? Argument `region` is no longer supported, creating provider aliases in different regions dynamically is also not supported. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use Provider [Aliasing](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations) and regions are reported as supported per the AWS provider [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs)

I suggest keeping your terraform cleanly modularized when using aliasing to keep the copy/paste code per region to a minimum

Check out this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981403/can-terraform-be-used-simply-to-create-resources-in-different-aws-regions) already addressing this for an implementation example (the latest answer 2021)

Comment: I was hoping for something more concise, something like `for_each` for providers, but yes, I guess modules with provider parameters is the best compromise at this time. Thanks!